# how to manage the impact of Covid on building a machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, prediction, data-science, training-datasets

I need your suggestions for using historical data to build a machine learning model for analyzing the market and build an AI model(tree based model/random forest or regression analysis) for setting the price.

I have data from these years:

- < 2020
- 2020
- 2021
- 2022

I am not confident about predictive power of pre covid data, my question form data scientist guys is how they manage the probable effect of covid. I divided my historical data as above because I think we have

- pre-covid, normal data,
- covid-time and its shock
- after-covid data, data with the impact of covid
- next-normal, I am not even sure that the industry meets new normal or not

do you have any guide line that says how to start, I need a framework to manage these data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.